# SHAP - subplot parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I would like my code to create a SHAP beeswarm plot and then save it as a png in a shared directory. This works

```
clf = xgboost.XGBClassifier(random_state=42)
model = clf.fit(X, y)

explainer = Explainer(model)
sv = explainer(X)

fig = plt.figure()

shap.plots.beeswarm(sv, max_display = 25, show = False)

plt.title("Feature importance") 
plt.xlim([-2, 2])
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(50,10)

plt.savefig('C:\temp\graphic.png')
```

However, the saved png is small and cuts off the labels of the features. If I go `plt.show()` instead of `plt.savefig('C:\temp\graphic.png')`, then I can interact with the graph and set `left` in the subplot config to make the full labels show.

How can I set this value when generating the png?

Comment: not able to test if it works now, but if memory serves I had the same or a similar problem and solved it with `plt.savefig(path, bbox_inches="tight")`